# $\;x^{52}=x^{-4}\cdot r^7\;$ what will be the value of r?

Tags: exponentiation

If $x^{52}=x^{-4}\cdot r^7$ then what will be the value of $r$?

Comment: Please fix your math notation. Currently it's incomprehensible. Are you using MathJax?

Comment: Since $x^{-4}$ couldn't make sense if $x=0$ we can safely assume that $x\neq 0$.  Multiply both sides by $x^4$ then to arrive at the equality $x^{56}=r^7$.  Continue.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $$x^4\neq 0$$ we get
$$x^{56}=r^7$$ so $$r=\sqrt[7]{x^{56}}$$